# How to add contents into FragmentTabsPager when the content is defined as Activity?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I am using The FragmentTabsPager, but not sure how to assign the contents of one of the tabs when the content itself is a complicated Activity that embeds ListViews, and a host of other activities. This is only for small one pane screen, so can I attach this Activity inside one of the tabs without changing the whole thing into a Fragment class? Is it right to simply change : onCreate to on onCreateView (inflate) and this becomes getActivity()?

EDIT: http://www.themobilemontage.com/

Download in the link above

Tutorial 9: Integrating Web Services Into Your Android App

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=QTO5a1IeBl8

The Main class is edu.gvsu.cis.toptracks.TopTrackListActivity which extends from Activity, so not sure how to convert this class (into a Fragment or FragmentActivity?) and place it as one of the tab contents if I start a new Blank Activity from template Blank Activity -> Navigation Type -> Fixed Tabs + Swipe.

Any suggestions as I tried to change the TopListActivity but not really clear what to do?

if I could convert this

Answer (score 0):

There is no `FragmentTabsPager` in Android. You cannot embed an activity into a `FragmentTabHost`, which is what I assume you mean. You can convert your activities to fragments, then use those with `FragmentTabHost` or any of the other modern tab solutions for Android.

> This is only for small one pane screen, so can I attach this Activity inside one of the tabs without changing the whole thing into a Fragment class?

No. Activities-in-tabs has been deprecated for well over two years.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I meant from the ActionBarSherlock library.

Comment: @SebastianC.: There is no `FragmentTabsPager` in ActionBarSherlock, either.

Comment: HI @CommonwWare. FramentTabsPager from one of the demos from ActionBar examples.. Trying to convert this Activity to Fragement please help as I changed Activity to Fragment, created onStart(), onCreatView() and changed 'this' to getActivity(), but many errors as now methods like onCreateOptionsMenu are no longer valid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTO5a1IeBl8. Or better to move these other methods within the previous Activity(now Fragment) into a new Activity class?

Comment: @SebastianC.: You are welcome to open a fresh StackOverflow question, to try to get help as you try to "convert this Activity to Fragement".

Comment: Hi, what if I modify the class so now extends from FragmentActivity? Can it now be one of the Tab contents?

Comment: So an Activity has to be converted into a Fragment before it can be used in ViewPagerIndicator, SwipeyTab demos seen ?

Comment: @SebastianC.: Typically, yes. You could somehow convert the activity into some sort of custom `View` instead, though converting it to a fragment is usually simpler.